# CiviBooking Installation

Tags: extension, civibooking

I have tried to load CiviBooking extension in the Demos.  They install fine and are enabled, yet I cannot access anything that resembles elements of a booking extension.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you need additions CMS permissions and won't be able to set them via the Demo sites.